# Add button in the admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I needed to add a button in the admin interface just before an Inline. What I've made is add the following in *change_form*:

```
{% block after_field_sets %}
<input type="button" value="Add contract" onClick=" window.location.href='../../contract/add/' ">
{% endblock %}
```

But...now the button is shown in every model page of the admin interface not just in the page of the Inline.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the template [for desired model only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories).  So template should be `templates/admin/my_app/my_model/change_form.html` instead of simple `templates/admin/change_form.html`